# Loading Packages in R

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

```
library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘vctrs’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.3 

library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘vctrs’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to load packages in Rstudio, but facing the above errors.

Comment: It seems that you have to install package `vctrs`: `install.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: Try `install.packages("vctrs")`.

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/vctrs_0.3.4.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/vctrs_0.3.4.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘vctrs’ failed

Comment: There is no file in Cran.

Comment: Can you install from github? `devtools::install_github("r-lib/vctrs")`

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up at Cran, whether vctrs 0.3.4 exists and it looks like version 0.3.4 only exists for macOS. As I can see from the URL you have posted in the comments you're using the OS Windows. And for Windows only vctrs 0.3.3 exists.

So my suggestion (little bit ugly but well...): Download the zip-src of vctrs 0.3.3 manually and then you can choose in RStudio to install from the zip file you've downloaded.
Or my other suggestion you can use: install.packages.zip("zip-url-manually-copied"), for more look: https://rdrr.io/cran/installr/man/install.packages.zip.html.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I got solved, I need to upgrade my R. Previously I am using version 3.6.0 and now I upgraded to 4.0.2, after upgrade everything works fine.